# How to change sender name from Gitlab emails

Tags: email, templates, gitlab

When I installed Gitlab on one of our servers I didn't realize that the first user would be the Gitlab Admin User and every time Gitlab sends a notification it appears that I'm the one who sends the email (only the name the email is the one in config/gitlab.yml)

How can I change that?

Thanks.

Comment: @Harry: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original answer (July 2014, GitLab 7.8.0)

You can see the `sender` function in [`app/mailers/notify.rb#L30`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/9dbd7e5aec921e43f3ea89c8e3357ca0174b0937/app/mailers/notify.rb#L39-L54):

```rb
# The default email address to send emails from
  def default_sender_address
    address = Mail::Address.new(Gitlab.config.gitlab.email_from)
    address.display_name = "GitLab"
    address
  end
```

That is the function you could change.

Update July 2016 (2 years later, GitLab 8.9.0+)

The updated code is still in [`app/mailers/notify.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/fe9246bf6850c35ee880ec9f67af5090c537a68a/app/mailers/notify.rb#L41-L61)

---

Update Dec. 2018 (GitLab 11.6)

The [email specs](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/055ec4dc0ae1fd765ee1e624f307bf2b00fa4c12/spec/mailers/shared/notify.rb#L22-L27) still shows:

```rb
shared_examples 'an email sent from GitLab' do
  it 'is sent from GitLab' do
    sender = subject.header[:from].addrs[0]
    expect(sender.display_name).to eq(gitlab_sender_display_name)
    expect(sender.address).to eq(gitlab_sender)
end
```

Which means some emails are sent with gitlab_sender_display_name, which is defined as:

```rb
let(:gitlab_sender_display_name) { Gitlab.config.gitlab.email_display_name }
```

Changing that `gitlab.email_display_name` should change the "GitLab" sender.

[Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663447/harry) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834339/how-to-change-sender-name-from-gitlab-emails/24837247#comment94676935_24837247):

> We now have [in `/config/initializers/1_settings.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/5dc656fc1f053d397ad1e6c1d85a815f03a5d634/config/initializers/1_settings.rb#L123)

```rb
Settings.gitlab['email_display_name'] ||= ENV['GITLAB_EMAIL_DISPLAY_NAME'] || 'GitLab'
                                                                              ^^^^^^^^
```

The `ENV` part comes from [commit 82bfa8f, GitLab v8.4.0v2, Dec. 2015](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/82bfa8f40c9ee7d292e8c4f8543cca27ca2c3c25).

Comment: I see, we now have `Settings.gitlab['email_display_name'] ||= ENV['GITLAB_EMAIL_DISPLAY_NAME'] || 'GitLab'` in `/config/initializers/1_settings.rb` Thanks.

Comment: @Harry Well spotted. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, adding a link to the `1_settings.rb` source code.